# The images are not displaying in firefox while in google chrome its displaying

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am showing images in chorme working fine. but when it is being shown in firefox it is not showing properly. what i do please give me suggestion and help me i have also used the **reset.css** file to remove browser styles but still same problem .

Comment: Show some code pls, without it it's impossible to guess, what your problem might be

Comment: I would suggest running it through a code validator to exclude any coding errors.

Comment: Can you please post the code here

Answer (score 0):

No one here can help you solve your problem without seeing your code that is being executed. But here are two solutions that might fix your problem:

1) Make sure you are using a forward slash `/` instead of back slash `\` when writing the path of your image.

```
Correct: <img src="/images/sample.png"> 
Incorrect: <img src="\images\sample.png">
```

2) Remove the two dots at the beginning of the path folder name if you have them.

```
<img src="../images/sample.png">
```